# JavaScript browser detection works but shows 'undefined' after

Tags: javascript, browser, undefined

I have put the following code in my website to check which browser I'm in:

```
function myFunction() {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
        document.write('Opera');
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
        document.write('Google Chrome');
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        document.write('Safari');
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        document.write('Firefox');
    } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) { //IF IE > 10
        document.write('IE (Internet Explorer)');
    } else {
        document.write('Browser Undefined');
    }
}
document.write(myFunction());
```

The code works fine. When I'm in Google Chrome, it show's the name but with the word 'undefined' next to the browser name.

Comment: return the browser name

Comment: @SagarV what do you mean by that?

Comment: `myFunction` has no return statement ... so, as javascript is written this way, this is identical to `return undefined`

Comment: @DamiënPeerbolte Instead of `document.write` in function, use `return 'Awesome Browser Name';`.

Comment: what you SHOULD do is change all `document.write` in `myFunction` to `return` ...

Comment: store the browser name in a var and return it

Comment: or just return it

Comment: and once you've done all that, learn that `browser detection` is meaningless as any (modern) browser can have the user agent set to anything

Comment: @DamiënPeerbolte I mean this https://jsfiddle.net/sagarvd01/2knt55df/
If you understood that code, you're awesome ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
        return 'Opera'
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
        return 'chome'
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
         return 'Safar'
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
       return 'Foxy'
    } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) { //IF IE > 10
        return 'MIS'
    } else {
       return document.write('Browser Undefined');
    }
}
document.write(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code like

```js
function myFunction() {
  var browser = "";
  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Opera'
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    browser = 'chrome'
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    browser = 'Safar'
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
    browser = 'Foxy'
  } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) { //IF IE > 10
    browser = 'MIS'
  } else {
    browser = 'Browser Undefined';
  }
  return browser;
}
document.write(myFunction());
```